# Groupe_concat max length in postgres?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

is there a way to set, like in the SQL example below, groupe_concat max length in Postgres?

```
SET group_concat_max_len=15000000;
```

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such configuration parameter.

The maximum length of the result of `string_agg()`  (or any other string concatenation) is limited by the maximum length of a text value in Postgres which is 1GB.